# How to send operations enums in angular services

Tags: angular, service, enums, get

I am working on angular.i am sending calling a api, I want to send a get request with enums. Can anyone answers how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand.
Do you want to send an enum value as a parameter to a get request?
If yes, then the request will be the same as any other request. Just add the parameter to an URL.

'''let myUrl = "example.com?myenumname=myenumvalue" '''